# Ninject no kernel has been registered for the web application

Tags: asp.net, ninject.web.mvc

I just inherited a program that is written in Framework 4.8.  This is an asp.net application.  When we try to hit a login page on our site we get this error:

> > Event code: 3005  Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.  Event time: 2/26/2021 11:35:59 AM  Event time (UTC):
> > 2/26/2021 6:35:59 PM  Event ID: a930ec5b24ce461cb7ea325a5a3df94d
> > Event sequence: 10  Event occurrence: 5  Event detail code: 0
> > Application information:
> > Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/ControlRoom-1-132588368625020589
> > Trust level: Full
> > Application Virtual Path: /ControlRoom
> > Application Path: [path to app]
> > Machine name: 945597-PREVIDEN    Process information:
> > Process ID: 2680
> > Process name: w3wp.exe
> > Account name: IIS APPPOOL\login.controlroom    Exception information:
> > Exception type: InvalidOperationException
> > Exception message: The type ASP.usercontrols_usernamepasswordlogin_ascx requested an injection,
> > but no kernel has been registered for the web application. Please
> > ensure that your project defines a NinjectHttpApplication.    at
> > Ninject.Web.KernelContainer.Inject(Object instance)    at
> > System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)    at
> > System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)    at
> > System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)    at
> > System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)    at
> > System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)    at
> > System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)    at
> > System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> > includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> ```
> Request information: 
> Request URL: [url]Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/controlroom
>
> Request path: /ControlRoom/Login.aspx 
> User host address: [host IP] 
> User:  
> Is authenticated: False 
> Authentication Type:  
> Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\login.controlroom    Thread information: 
> Thread ID: 62 
> Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\login.controlroom 
> Is impersonating: False 
> Stack trace:    at Ninject.Web.KernelContainer.Inject(Object instance)    at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
> ```
>
> namingContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
> namingContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
> namingContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
> namingContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
> namingContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
> namingContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I have tried resetting the application pool, redeploying the site and even doing a restart of the whole server but it continues to fail. I have no experience with Ninject and I am clueless as to what can be the problem or the solution.  The main site that hosts this page is working, it is just this page that is failing.  I can provide code if needed but I don't know what would be useful at this time. The site is using Ninject 3.2.0

Comment: This site runs just fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a problem with the connection string in the web.config file.  Once we pointed it to the right location, it started working again.  It had nothing to do with the Ninject, that was where the error was captured and thrown which in turn, threw us off the actual problem.